# Concatenate filters in django query

Tags: python, django

I want to do the following thing:

lets say I have:

```
query_terms = ["A", "B"]
```

And what is needed is the following query:

```
House.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains="A") | Q(building__name__icontains="A",
    Q(name__icontains="B") | Q(building__name__icontains="B"
)
```

I don't know how to join this "OR" statements together with "AND" having a dynamic query_terms list

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
full_query = None
for query in query_terms:
    q = Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(building__name__icontains=query)
    if full_query is None:
        full_query = q
    else:
        full_query = full_query & q
```

I'm probably not optimizing this exactly right, but something along these lines should work.

Comment: Excelent, as soon as I can, I'll give the the tick! Thanks you so much